# html make drag item disappear on drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to make the draggable item disappear when dropped on a target.

Here's what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #div1 {
            width: 350px;
            height: 70px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
        }

        #div2 {
            width: 100px;
            height: 30px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 3px solid #aaaaaa;
            position: absolute;
            left: 10px;
            top: 240px
        }

        #draggable {
            width: 100px;
            height: 30px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 3px solid #aaaaaa;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Drag the item into the rectangle:</p>

    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="30">This is a draggable item</div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried by adding this script to it:-

```
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event)  {
    event.target.style.opacity = "0.0";
});
```

This makes the item disappear, but it does this as soon as you start to drag it. If you drop it anywhere you can't see it.

I changed "dragstart" to "drop" and this works, but it also makes the target `area(div1)` disappear.

Comment: @ erik Not sure what you edit but it is still the same

Comment: You can see what he edited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33805113/revisions).

Comment: Not sure what happened there as the bits that have been edited was not on my original copy. The problem is still there. When you start to drag it disappears.I do not want this to happen .Only disappear once on target.I you drop item off target it is invisible ,so not an ideal solution.